# find list of patterns from file not matching in another file unix

Tags: unix, command-line, awk, grep

I can't seem to be able to wrap my head around this simple problem.
I need to print all patterns that are in fileA but not int fileB.

Consider fileA to be as :

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

And consider fileB to be as :

```
ppppppppppppp_aaa_ppppppppppppp
ppppppppppppp_ccc_ppppppppppppp
ppppppppppppp_ddd_ppppppppppppp
```

I want the following result :

```
bbb
```

I have tried

```
grep -f -v fileA fileB
grep -F -v -f fileA fileB
```

but it does not seems to work as nothing is printed.

How can I achieve this in a unix command?

Thank you

Comment: You probably have to read each line in file A, check whether it appears in file B (a separate invocation of `grep`) and report appropriately. There are options and techniques to suppress noise from the `grep` commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec < fileA
while read line; do
    grep -q "$line" fileB || echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: I'd suggest that instead of `count` etc. simply say `grep -q "$line" fileB || echo "$line"`.

Comment: @devnull - Very nice.  You should post that as another answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'_' 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next}!(a[$0]){print}' fileB fileA
```

Tested below:

```
> cat fileA
ppppppppppppp_aaa_ppppppppppppp
ppppppppppppp_ccc_ppppppppppppp
ppppppppppppp_ddd_ppppppppppppp
> cat fileB
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
> awk -F'_' 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next}!(a[$0]){print}' fileA fileB
bbb
>
```